# How to remove group in Empathy?

Tags: 10.10, empathy

I have created a new group in Empathy IM by right-clicking on a contact, then Edit and Add Group.

How do I remove a group?

**UPDATE:**

OK, obviously Murat Gunes answer is correct, but that's not exactly what I meant. When I right click on the group name and select Remove it removes the group from the main window.

However, the group is not purged from the system. When I right-click on a contact again and select Edit, I can still see the group in the list and I can even put a contact into that group, which then makes it appear again in the main window.

Answer (score 2):

Right-click the group title and hit "Remove".

Comment: That's right, but it does not remove it from the system. See my update above.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to remove them for Windows Live (possibly from the web client, or the Windows client itself) in order to have them permanently gone...

Answer (score 0):

Do what Murat says and then restart Empathy (not just closing the window, but really quit it, then start Empathy again).

Comment: Groups are still present with rightclick->Edit.

Comment: They aren't for me...  Are you sure there were no more contacts with that group left?  (E.g. contacts that were hidden because they weren't online?)

Comment: Yes, there is only one contact in the group. This is needed, otherwise the group won't show up in the main window. Then I rightclick->Remove and the group disappears. Then exit and restart and the group is still there when rightclicking on contact and Edit.